# Scala: execute anonymous code block for None value in Option

Tags: scala

Option class has a good method `foreach`, which calls passed code if value is specified. Is there any similar techinque for `None` value? I know about `.orElse` method, but, using it, I am required to return `Option` from code block:

```
x orElse {
    // do something
    None // <-- I want to avoid this line
}
```

Comment: an Option is by definition designed to force you to manage the None case, so you shouldn't be able to avoid the None

Comment: @sam, but my question is about handling `None`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do something in the `None` case I assume you are side-effecting. So what's wrong with:

```
if(o.isEmpty){
  // do things
}
```

Comment: I want to do something when there is no result. For example, I want do api request only if there is no database results. Why is it side-effecting?

Comment: It is side-effecting because you are not returning a value since you are only interested in one case (the `None`).  Don't worry about that.  The point is the library doesn't have a "noneForeach" so you're better off just using `if(o.isEmpty)`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that it exists in standard Option library, but you can add it with implicit class

```
class OptionFunctions[T](val opt: Option[T]) extends AnyVal {
  def ifEmpty[A](f: => A): Unit = {
    if (opt.isEmpty) f
  } 
}
```

and use it like this:

```
val o = Some(1)
o.ifEmpty { println("empty") }
```

Comment: Yes, it will work. But my question is more about _proper_ way to do this. For example, I may simply check `isEmpty` with `if` statement.

Comment: there is no *proper* way, it's design choice completely up to you

Answer (score 1):

A pattern match perhaps?

```
option match {
   case Some(foo) => println("Have " + foo)
   case None => println("Have nothing.")
}
```

Comment: This is simplies solution, but I want to write more functional-style code.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "function-style code" exactly, but pattern matching is quite idiomatic scala ...

Comment: I often ask myself the same question as the OP only to realize that I am indeed handling both cases without needing the result (e.g. `x.map(...).orElse(...)`. In this case, pattern matching is a better way.